# django annotation max min AND first last

Tags: django, annotations, aggregation

From a datatable that stores the BTC price each minute, I'am trying to get an queryset objet that aggregate values by hours (need min, max, first and last). It works well for the max and min

class BTCDayDataCandles(APIView):
authentification_classes = []
permission_classes = []

```
def get(self, request, format=None):
    now = datetime.now()
    BTCData = BTCminute.objects\
        .annotate(test = Trunc('dateTimeEntry', 'hour'))\
        .order_by('-test')\
        .values('test')\
        .annotate(Max('price'), Min('price'))

    data = {
       'BTCData': BTCData,
    }
    print(BTCData)
    return Response(data)
```

How can I add the fist and last price value for each hour in the queryset Object?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#first)
Returns the first object matched by the queryset, or None if there is no matching object. If the QuerySet has no ordering defined, then the queryset is automatically ordered by the primary key.

.